# Why does my roomChoice keep printing out 1 instead of the other room number?

Tags: python

Trying to make a game.

when I input a direction to go to the next room it just takes me straight back to the START_ROOM which is what I set it as but I want to be able to switch between different rooms

I tried changing the input, but nothing works I would just go to that room and only that one.

Just need help with the movement function.

I think the problem is that I don't know how to properly assign a user input in between functions.

```
import random
import sys

START_ROOM = 1
FINAL_ROOM = 6
START_GOLD = 10
goldAmount = START_GOLD
chealth = 10
thealth = 10 
pdamage = 1
roomChoice = START_ROOM
visited_room = False
gameOver = False
global c, t , p, r
p = pdamage
t = thealth
c = chealth
r = roomChoice

 

def room1(goldAmount, visited_room, chealth):
    print("Your health has been set to {0} health".format(chealth))
    

    if visited_room == False:
        story1()
        gold = 10 # This is the amount of gold the room contains.
    
        print()
        print("The room has", gold, "gold pieces in it...")
        goldAmount += gold
        print("After taking the gold, you currently have", goldAmount, "gold pieces in your posession...")
        print()
        # Mark the room as 'visited'
        visited_room = True
        shop()
        combat()
    else:
        print(visited_room)
        print("You have already visited room  1 before...")
        shop()
        print()
    
    direction = input("What direction do you want to go [n]orth, [ns]north south, [s]outh, [se]south east, [e]ast, [w]est?: ")
    while direction != "n" and direction != "s" and direction != "e" and direction != "w" and direction != "ns" and direction != "se":
        print("Invalid input...")
        direction = input("[n]orth, [ns]north south, [s]outh, [se]south east, [e]ast, [w]est: ")
    return movement(roomChoice, goldAmount, visited_room, chealth)
    


def movement(a, b, c, d):
    a = roomChoice
    b = goldAmount
    c = visited_room
    d = chealth

    while d < 0:
        if direction == "n":
            a = 2
            print("Room 2")

        elif direction == "ns":
            a = 1
            print("Room 5")

        elif direction == "s":
            a = 3 
            print("Room 3")
            
        elif direction == "e":
            a = 4 
            print("Room 4")
            
        elif direction == "w":
            a = 5  
            print("Room 5")
        elif direction == "se":
            a = 6 
            print("Room 6")
        else:
            gameOver == True

    return (a,b,c,d)



def main():
    gameOver = False
    START_GOLD = 0
    goldAmount = START_GOLD
    currentRoom = START_ROOM
    thealth = 10
    chealth = 10
    pdamage = 1
    visited_room1 = False 
    visited_room2 = False
    visited_room3 = False
    visited_room4 = False
    visited_room5 = False
    visited_room6 = False
    print("Welcome to Dungeon Crawl...")
    print()
    
    
    while gameOver == False:
        choice = input("MAIN MENU: [p]lay, [i]nstructions, or [q]uit?: ")
        print()
        if choice == "p": 
            print("Your current Health is ", chealth,"/",thealth, " and ", "Your player damage is ", pdamage)
            
            while currentRoom != FINAL_ROOM: 
                if currentRoom == 1:
                    currentRoom, goldAmount, visited_room1,chealth = room1(goldAmount, visited_room1, chealth)
                elif currentRoom == 2:
                    currentRoom, goldAmount, visited_room2,chealth = room2(goldAmount, visited_room2, chealth)
                elif currentRoom == 3:
                    currentRoom, goldAmount, visited_room3,chealth = room3(goldAmount, visited_room3, chealth)
                elif currentRoom == 4:
                    currentRoom, goldAmount, visited_room4,chealth = room4(goldAmount, visited_room4, chealth)
                elif currentRoom == 5:
                    currentRoom, goldAmount, visited_room4,chealth = room4(goldAmount, visited_room5, chealth)
                elif currentRoom == 6:
                    currentRoom, goldAmount, visited_room4,chealth = room4(goldAmount, visited_room6, chealth)
                else:
                    print("Error - currentRoom number", currentRoom, "does not correspond with available rooms")
                    sys.exit()
            
            
            if (chealth > 0):
                print()
                print("You have escaped with", chealth, "and", goldAmount, "gold from the dungeon!")
                print()
                gameOver = False
                goldAmount = START_GOLD
                currentRoom = START_ROOM
                thealth = 10
                chealth = 10
                pdamage = 1
                visited_room1 = False 
                visited_room2 = False
                visited_room3 = False
                visited_room4 = False
                visited_room5 = False
                visited_room6 = False
            else:
                print("You have perished in the dungeon")
                print("Game Over")
                gameOver == True
          
                thealth = 10
                chealth = thealth
                pdamage = 1
                goldAmount = START_GOLD
                currentRoom = START_ROOM
                visited_room1 = False
                visited_room2 = False
                visited_room3 = False
                visited_room4 = False
                visited_room5 = False
                visited_room6 = False
        elif choice == "i": 
            print()
            print("Adventure around the dangerous dungeon and collect the gold")
            print("Beware of the dangers that live in the shadows of the dark dungeon")
            print()
        elif choice == "q": 
            gameOver == True
            print("Good Bye!")
            print()
            quit()
            
        else:
            print()
            print("Please enter [p], [i], or [q]...")
            print()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
while d < 0:
```

to

```
while d > 0:
```

At the moment you'll only move room if the health is less than 0. There is an additional error that `direction` isn't defined in the `movement` function but that isn't what is causing your specific problem.